# ActiveRecord's query misbehaviour for outer joins?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Lets have two ActiveRecord models `Product` and `Promotion`

Building query with outer join and alias for joined table column produces following invalid SQL:

```
Product.distinct.includes(:promotion).select('promotions.advertised as featured').
references(:promotion).order('featured').limit(10).to_sql

SELECT  DISTINCT "products"."id", featured AS alias_0 FROM "products"
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "promotions" ON "promotions"."product_id" = "products"."id"  ORDER BY featured LIMIT 10
```

Execution results in database error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "featured" does not exist`. As expected, because *featured* is alias to *promotions.advertised* column, not defined in table *products*.

As you can see, ActiveRecord injects invalid `"featured AS alias_0"` expression into select. In addition, all columns of `products` table, except `id`, are omitted.

Above misbehavior is related to simultaneous use of `order` AND `limit` methods. When any of them is omitted, produced SQL becomes correct. For example just single removal of *limit* produces right query:

```
Product.distinct.includes(:promotion).select('promotions.advertised as featured').
references(:promotion).order('featured').to_sql

SELECT  DISTINCT promotions.advertised as featured, "products"."id" AS t0_r0, "products"."name" AS t0_r1, … FROM "products"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "promotions" ON "promotions"."product_id" = "products"."id"  ORDER BY featured
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour ?

Candidate for a bugreport or am I missing something ?

*tested with ActiveRecord ver. 4.2.7.1*

Comment: `distinct` is not a problem. No effect on fixing invalid query when omitted. I've tried simplify much more complex problem, but the basic idea is kept. I don't quite understand what you mean by *"fighting"* above methods, why they shouldn't be used together.

Comment: By "fighting" I mean that `distinct`, `includes`, and `select` are all trying to do things to the SELECT clause and it looks like they end up screwing it up.

Comment: I still can't see any ambiguity or improper usage of those methods. What bugs me out, and should probably others, it silently returns obviously wrong result, just by adding quite unrelated `limit` method.